# Call from asm external function with double argument

Tags: c++, function, assembly, x86, double

i'm trying to make c++ and asm work together with real values, i know that if i want to return from asm to c++ float or double i just need to leave it in st(0) (as i should leave return value in eax in case of integer and others), but what if i want to call from assembly code function that accepts double as a parameter? i can't put it in normal stack because it accepts max of dword (4 bytes) and double is qword (8 bytes), passing it via coprocessor stack doesn't work (tried it just to be sure :D), any suggestions?

```
.386
.model flat, stdcall

getZeroPoint proto func: dword, startPoint: qword, epsilon: qword, out_iterCount: dword
getDerivative proto func: dword, point: qword

.data
derivativeEpsilon dword 0.0000001
.code

getDerivative proc, func: dword, point: qword
    ;call somehow func with argument point
getDerivative endp

getZeroPoint proc, func: dword, startPoint: qword, epsilon: qword, out_iterCount: dword
    finit
    ;call somehow getDerivative with argument startPoint
    ret
getZeroPoint endp

end
```

where "func" is pointer to double function with double argument (pointer passed from c++ code), startPoint and epsilon are doubles (don't mention out_iterCount, it's pointer to integer, so there is no problems)

there is c++ code in case you need it too:

```
#include <iostream>
extern "C" double __stdcall getZeroPoint(double (*func)(double), double startPoint, double epsilon, int* out_iterCount);

double f(double argument)
{
    return argument * argument;
    //return tan(argument) - argument;
}

int main()
{
    int iterCount;
    std::cout << getZeroPoint(&f, 5.0, 0.0001, &iterCount) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: reading for you - https://itanium-cxx-abi.github.io/cxx-abi/abi.html

Comment: You put the double on the stack. Nothing prevents you from putting 8 bytes of data on the stack and passing it as a parameter. You just have to push the high 4 bytes of the double float on the stack and then the lower 4 bytes.

Comment: Please tag all [tag:assembly] questions with the tag for the architecture you are using.  I added the [tag:x86] tag for you.

Comment: asm doesn't allows me to push qword variable directly (error "invalid instruction operands"), i don't have ideas how to add high 4 bytes first and then low 4 bytes, also tried to put registry in between (saw somewhere 8 bytes "rax" registry), but it occurs i don't have it..

Comment: You have to do it in 2 parts. 4 bytes each. Same applies for 64-bit integers. With the FPU as well if you have a value is on the coprocessor stack you can use the FST instruction to write all 8 bytes to the stack with one instruction (although you have to allocate the stack space first)

Comment: i got it that i need to do it in 2 parts, but how can i push only first 4 bytes or only second 4 bytes of a variable? in case of FPU - FST can store only in memory variables, it can't store into default stack

Comment: seems logic, missed that part, but even in that case, i can't FST high 4 bytes and then lower 4 bytes of value, for example if ST(0) contains some double and i do FST to float it will just cut value to float because ST contains tbytes and cuts values every time you do FST

Comment: FST can store to memory. The stack is memory.  For instance let us say there is some value at the top the FPU coprocessor stack and I wish to place it on the the program stack I would do something like `sub esp, 8` to allocate 8 bytes on the stack and then do `fstp qword ptr [esp]` . Doing those two instructions would be the equivalent of pushing an 8 byte value on the stack. I use FSTP so it pops the value off the coprocessor stack although you can use FST if you don't want to remove the value from the coprocessor stack

Comment: i.. don't really understand "qword ptr" syntaxis there, i don't have anything similar in training manual given by teacher...

Comment: the qword ptr tells the assembler to generate the FST/FSTP instruction so that it writes a 64-bit float to memory. If you were to use DWORD PTR it would write a 32-bit float to memory. As well REAL8 PTR works the same as QWORD PTR since both denote a 64-bit size.

Comment: so it's like a work-around for case when you need to store data via pointer and now via variable where asm can take variable's size to know how many bytes to store?

Comment: If you define a variable called `mydbl` like this in your d`.data` section using `mydbl real8 32.31` you can then push that 8 byte double float on the stack using `push dword ptr [mydbl+4]` then `push dword ptr [mydbl]`

Comment: but mydbl in that case contains value and not a pointer to a value, isn't it? but it looks like u treat it like a pointer with ptr and square brackets..

Comment: `push dword ptr [mydbl+4]` means take the 32-bit value at memory address mydbl+4 (the upper 4 bytes of mydbl) and push that value on the program stack. `push dword ptr [mydbl]` means take the value at memory address mydbl (the lower 32-bits of mydbl) and push that value on the program stack. `fstp qword ptr [esp]` meant take the 64-bit float from the top of the FPU stack and move its value (all 64-bits) to the memory address pointed to by ESP (FSTP then pops the value off the FPU stack)

Comment: it was square brackets messing with my mind, cause as i knew before - they means that we go to the memory address specified in variable (register) inside of brackets, so i thought dword ptr [mydbl + 4] means we add to mydbl value 4, go to this address and then do something with it's pointer, i tried removing square brackets and everything still works.. and it's easier to understand in my case :D

Comment: In MASM `push dword ptr [mydbl+4]` and `push dword ptr mydbl+4` are the same thing (for the most part MASM ignores the []). I must make this clear that is not pushing a pointer on the stack. It is the 32-bits of data at the address mydbl+4 that is being pushed on the stack.

Comment: that's the thing, square brackets made opposite, i thought you are trying to push what were at address stored in mydbl (this address plus four, of course), cause commonly square brackets means "take what is at the address, which stored in this variable" as far as i know, but in any case, i got it working at least, now just need to finish Newton alghorithm, thanks)

Comment: In MASM the square brackets in this case don't mean anything. MASM allows it either way. The `PTR` in the instruction says you are dealing with data at a memory address. In MASM if you wanted for example to push the address of the upper 32-bits of `mydbl` you do `push offset mydbl+4`. IMHO, MASM has always made this more complicated than it had to be.